# DevEcoStudio: Previewer did not get installed

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I have an issue related to installing previewer. When I installed DevEcoStudio version 3.0.0.800, previewer did not get installed. On opening previewer it was showing error as "Getting SDK path failed".[image: Preivewer error]

Answer (score 0):

Pls try below:

Download the previewer of the corresponding SDK version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For DevEco Studio 3.0 Beta2 (version 3.0.0.800), after downloading SDK (APIs) and Previewer tools, you also need to enable HarmonyOS Ark and eTS Previewer from DevEco Labs as shown below.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ArkCompiler is not compatable to build HAPs/APPs for HarmonyOS 2.0.0(SDK6) or lower, If you would like to use ArkCompiler, you need a app for HarmonyOS 3.0.0(SDK7) or OpenHarmony 3.0 LTS.

Also, check your SDK installation, and check the emeulator option for your specified SDK.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).